# Отобразить контент

Tags: wordpress

всем привет!!! Помогите пожалуйста решить проблемку. Сверстал сайт и натягиваю его на WP. В настройках->чтение установил статическую страницу 'главная'. Теперь отображается только header & footer. Контент с index.php не отображается. Отображается как надо только если вернуть в настройках чтения 'последние записи'. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: front-page.php отвечает за галвную страницу. Читайте иерархию шаблонов

Comment: Читал. Но если я правильно понял, что если front-page.php не установлена то в ход идет index.php.

Comment: почти, там еще около 5 шаблонов между ними. Идите почитайте еще раз)

Comment: Ок)) Спасибо. Хорошего дня!!!